# How correctly assign value to field

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I am trying to assign value for one edit field(not asp.net control) in asp.net application using JavaScript code. It seems that **<** character in value string gives problems for ASP.NET. If I remove < and > characters from value everything works fine.

Where is the problem? How to pass <> characters to the field? I don't want to use ServerSide code I want to do it on ClientSide using JS and HTML Edit box.

```
        function loadShareBox(pageTitle) {
            document.getElementById("shareHTML").value = '<a href="' + document.location.href + '" target=_blank>' + pageTitle + '</a>';
        }
```

regards,
Tomas

Answer (score 1):

try using these

```
&lt; corresponds <
&gt; corresponds >
```

the code would look like this

```
    function loadShareBox(pageTitle) {
        document.getElementById("shareHTML").value = '&lt;a href="' + document.location.href + '" target=_blank&gt;' + pageTitle + '&lt;/a&gt;';
    }
```

edit: ah, I think there is another problem. You are trying to insert a new element within another element. So you should create a new element and append in shareHTML.

```
var myLink = document.createElement("a");
myLink.setAttribute("href", "mylink");
var text = document.createTextNode("Link name");
myLink.appendChild(text);
var myElement = document.getElementById("shareHTML")
myElement.appendChild(myLink);
```

this should do the work

Comment: shareHTML is html INPUT object. So appending A attribute to it is not correct, also &lt; and &gt; do not helps because they are not interpreted by browser and in INPUT control they appears as &lt; and &gt;, and not <>